# catch spark conntext exception with spec2

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, specifications, specs2

I'm trying to test some code that transforms dataframe to dataset[String]

I'm using the following spec2 code to test if my module throws an exception in specific condition.
the problem is that spec2 does trace the exception and failed the test even though the correct exception was thrown, 
is there a way to make spec2 to intercept spark's exceptions?

my test code:

```
class DataframeUtilTest extends Specification
{
  val spark:SparkSession =  SparkSession
    .builder()
    .master("local[2]")
    .getOrCreate()

  "dataframe utils" should {


    " throw an exception on struct type field" in {
      import spark.implicits._
      val valuesSequesnceRDD = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq((1L, 3.0, "a","2017-01-15 15:34:12",Seq(1,2,3))).
        map(x => Row(x._1,x._2,x._3,x._4,x._5)))
      val schema = StructType(Seq(StructField("user_id",LongType),
        StructField("filed2",DoubleType),
        StructField("name",StringType),
        StructField("date",StringType),
        StructField("array",ArrayType(IntegerType))))
      lazy val df = spark.createDataFrame(valuesSequesnceRDD,schema).
        withColumn("datetime",col("date").cast(TimestampType)).
        withColumn("date",col("date").cast(DateType)).
       withColumn("struct_all",struct("user_id","filed2","name","date"))
      df.map(jsonUtils.rowToJsonString) must throwA[Exception]
    }

  }
```

the code that should generate the error:

```
object jsonUtils{

  def rowToMap(row:Row):Map[String,Any]={
    val new_map = (row.schema.fieldNames zip row.toSeq).map(x=>x._1 -> x._2).toMap
//    finding if there is a struct type fields - we currently not supporting this
    if (new_map.exists(x => x._2.getClass.getName == "org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema")){
      throw new Exception("structType desiriliazation is not supported")
    }
    else{
      new_map
    }

  }
  def rowToJsonString(row:Row):String ={
        val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
            mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
            mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
            val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
            mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
            mapper.setDateFormat(dateFormat)
            mapper.writeValueAsString(rowToMap(row))
  }
}
```

the failed test message:

```
Expected: java.lang.Exception. Got nothing
java.lang.Exception: Expected: java.lang.Exception. Got nothing
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the call to `df.map(jsonUtils.rowToJsonString)` really throws an `Exception` and not a `Throwable` for example? To do this, run the code without `must throwAn[Exception]` and add `ok` after `df.map(...)` so that the code compiles. Specs2 should then catch the exception and report an error. Let's see what that exception looks like.

Comment: I created a main function in different scope and run the code under test, and it throw the expected error..

I can;t figure out how to add the "ok". it create a compilation error

Comment: Write `df.map(jsonUtils.rowToJsonString); ok` at the end of the test.

Comment: now it just passing the test..not going throw the relevant code

Comment: This makes me think that no exception is really thrown in the test, which would be an issue independent of specs2.